# Make pytest require code coverage only on full test suite run

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py, test-coverage

I am using something like

```
# .coveragerc
fail_under = 100
```

and

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = --cov=modname/ --cov-report=term-missing
```

to make it so that my test suite runs the coverage and fails if it isn't 100%.

This works, but the problem is that if I run only a subset of the tests, like

```
pytest some/specific/test.py
```

it then complains that the coverage is not 100%, because of course that one single test file doesn't cover the entire codebase. Is there a better way to make pytest run coverage, but only when running the full test suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a tip from https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/418#issuecomment-657219659, I came up with the following (in `conftest.py`):

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    if config.args not in [[], ['mylib'], ['mylib/']]:
        cov = config.pluginmanager.get_plugin('_cov')
        cov.options.no_cov = True
        if cov.cov_controller:
            cov.cov_controller.pause()
```

This also has the benefit of actually disabling coverage, not just the reporting, which makes the tests run faster in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily override your `.coveragerc` by adding the following flag to your command:

```sh
--cov-fail-under=x
```

where x is the percentage to fail under (if you set this to 0, it will never fail based on the code coverage)

Thus, in your case you would run:

```sh
pytest some/specific/test.py --cov-fail-under=x
```